# Apache VirtualHost with mod-proxy and SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-proxy

I am trying to setup a server with multiple web applications which will all be served through apache VirtualHost (apache running on the same server). My main constrain is that each web application must use SSL encryption. After googling for a while and looking other questions on stackoverflow, I wrote the following configuration for the VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
    ServerName host.domain.org

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/
</VirtualHost>
```

Even though https://host.domain.org:8443 is accessible, https://host.domain.org is not, which defeats the purpose of my virtual host configuration. Firefox complains that even though it successfully connected to the server, the connection was interrupted. Chrome return an error 107: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Finally I should also mention that the virtual host works perfectly fine when I do not use SSL.

How can I make this work ?

Thanks

Comment: This would probably fit in better on serverfault.com

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to configure SSL in both Apache and Tomcat.

The easiest way to accomplish that is configure SSL just on Apache and proxy to tomcat using http.

Comment: But then you lose the SSL context, which is useful if you're using webapps with the CLIENT-CERT authentication method.